# How to bit manipulate a mask into a number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

How can I change a range of bits in an unsigned byte (or bigger) without caring what are the current bits at those ranges.

0bXXXX'XXXX

I want to set bits at positions 2,3,4 to 0b101, so at the end the byte should become:

0bXXXX'101X

The mask for 2,3 and 4 bits I think will be 0b0000'1110 or 12

I tried:

```
unsigned char b = 255;
b = 0b101 &  ~( 12 << 1);
```

But this prints:

```
0000'0101
```

Comment: Use `|` to set bits.

Comment: `( x & ~0b100u ) | 0b1010u`

Comment: "0b0000'1110 or 12" To begin with, 1110 is 14 / 0xE. And the code you have clears all the surrounding bits by using &, so that's wrong too.

Comment: Clear bits: `byte &= ~(0b111 << 2)`. Set bits to some data: `byte |= 0b101 << 2;`. Although hex notation is usually preferred over binary, since binary tends to become an unreadable mess very soon. For example you could write this as an unreadable one-liner, which is very bad practice: `byte = (byte & ~(0b111 << 2)) | (0b101 << 2);`

Comment: I agree that the dupe target isn't a duplicate, since this is about a range of bits, not a single bit. Re-opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear bits: `byte &= ~(0b111 << 2);`
Set bits to some data: `byte |= 0b101 << 2;`

But note rule #1: no "magic numbers". Wth is 0b101 and why are we shifting it by 2? So start by defining named constants. If the bit-field we are dealing with is named "FOO", then for example:

```
#define FOO_POS    2
#define FOO_MASK   0x7u
#define FOO       (FOO_MASK << FOO_POS)
```

Complete example (C23):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO_POS    2
#define FOO_MASK   0x7u
#define FOO       (FOO_MASK << FOO_POS)

int main(void) 
{
  unsigned int bar = 0xFF;
  printf("%.2X %.8b\n", bar, bar);

  bar &= ~FOO;
  printf("%.2X %.8b\n", bar, bar);

  bar |= ((0b101 & FOO_MASK) << FOO_POS);
  printf("%.2X %.8b\n", bar, bar);
}
```

Just don't take such macros too far and start inventing some ugly setter/getter macro language for setting bits. C programmers are expected to know bitwise operations so there's no need to hide them behind ugly macros, as they are already the most clear when typed out explicitly.

Comment: Isn't `(0b101 & FOO_MASK)` redundant (it's always just `0b101`)?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica In this case where the data is a "magic number", then yes. In case `0b101` is stored in a variable or a named constant as it ought to, then no.